# How to "extend" the array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to extend the 2d array in python in some way.

No loops

F.e. if it is:

```
[[255, 255, 255],
     [255, 255, 255],
     [255, 255, 255]]
```

I would say I want to extend it by the factor of 2 and get like this:

```
[[255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0],
  [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0],
  [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0],
  [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]
```

and etc, if by 4 factor.

Is there any function?

Comment: if you reshape to one column then you could add second column with zeros and after reshaping back you should have vertical columns with zeros. You may need something similar to put horizontal rows with zeros.

Comment: or maybe first you should create new array 6x6 only with zeros and later copy values from old array

Comment: thank you, I corrected. As it is 2d array

Comment: Du you have lists or a numpy-array?

Comment: it is an array, but no problems to convert to lists

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without numpy just with list comprehension:

```
lst = [[255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255]]
extend_list = [ [lst[j // 2][i // 2] if j % 2 == 0 and i % 2 == 0 else 0 for i in range( 2 * (len(lst[j // 2])) )] if j != len(2 * lst) else [0 for _ in range( (2 * len(lst)) -1)] for j in range(2 * (len(lst)) )]

print(extend_list)
```

the output:

```
[[255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 0], [255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: yeah, I was thinking of it. But again here we deal with loops, right?

Comment: its not a loop, its list comprehension https://switowski.com/blog/for-loop-vs-list-comprehension

Comment: A list comprehension is still going through each element one at a time in contrast to vectorized numpy functions

Comment: `list comprehension` can be converted to normal `for`-loop and then it will be simpler.

Comment: Yes, it was difficult

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using numpy. You didn't provide example for N=4, so I guessed :

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]])
factor = 4

print(arr)
nx, ny = arr.shape
if nx != ny:
    raise Exception("Array is not square")

step = 2 + factor//2 - 1
stop = nx * step
print('stop:', stop)
print('step:', step)

for x in range(1,stop,step):
    print()
    nx, ny = arr.shape
    print('x:', x)
    value = [[0]*nx]*(factor//2)
    print('Inserting columns:', value)
    arr = np.insert(arr, x, value, axis=1)
    nx, ny = arr.shape
    print(arr)
    value = [[0]*ny]*(factor//2)
    print('Inserting rows:', value)
    arr = np.insert(arr, x, value, axis=0)
    print(arr)

[[255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]
 [255 255 255]]
stop: 9
step: 3

x: 1
Inserting columns: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[255   0   0 255 255]
 [255   0   0 255 255]
 [255   0   0 255 255]]
Inserting rows: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[255   0   0 255 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0   0 255 255]
 [255   0   0 255 255]]

x: 4
Inserting columns: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[255   0   0 255   0   0 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0   0 255   0   0 255]
 [255   0   0 255   0   0 255]]
Inserting rows: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[255   0   0 255   0   0 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0   0 255   0   0 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0   0 255   0   0 255]]

x: 7
Inserting columns: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[255   0   0 255   0   0 255   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0   0 255   0   0 255   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0   0 255   0   0 255   0   0]]
Inserting rows: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[255   0   0 255   0   0 255   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0   0 255   0   0 255   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0   0 255   0   0 255   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new bigger array with zeros

```
factor = 2

h, w = arr.shape[:2]

new_w = h*factor
new_h = h*factor

new_arr = np.zeros((new_h, new_w), np.uint8)
```

and then you can use `for`-loops with `zip()` and `range(0, new_h, factor)` to get value and its new position

```
for row, y in zip(arr, range(0, new_h, factor)):
    for value, x in zip(row, range(0, new_w, factor)):
        new_arr[y,x] = value
```

gives

```
[[255   0 255   0 255   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0 255   0 255   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0 255   0 255   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

If you use different value instead of `0` in `range` then you can get `offset`

```
offset_y = 1
offset_x = 1
for row, y in zip(arr, range(offset_y, new_h, factor)):
    for value, x in zip(row, range(offset_x, new_w, factor)):
        new_arr[y,x] = value
```

gives:

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 255   0 255   0 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 255   0 255   0 255]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 255   0 255   0 255]]
```

---

Working code

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[255, 255, 255],
     [255, 255, 255],
     [255, 255, 255]]
)

factor = 2

h, w = arr.shape[:2]

new_w = h*factor
new_h = h*factor

new_arr = np.zeros((new_h, new_w), np.uint8)

offset_x = 0
offset_y = 0
for row, y in zip(arr, range(offset_y, new_h, factor)):
    #print(row, y)
    for value, x in zip(row, range(offset_x, new_w, factor)):
        #print(y, x, value)
        new_arr[y,x] = value
        
print(new_arr)
```

---

**BTW:** You could even use `factor_x`, `factor_y` with different values.

for example

```
factor_x = 4
factor_y = 2
```

in code

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[255, 255, 255],
     [255, 255, 255],
     [255, 255, 255]]
)

factor_x = 4
factor_y = 2

h, w = arr.shape[:2]
new_w = h*factor_x
new_h = h*factor_y
new_arr = np.zeros((new_h, new_w), np.uint8)

offset_x = 0
offset_y = 0
for row, y in zip(arr, range(offset_y, new_h, factor_y)):
    #print(row, y)
    for value, x in zip(row, range(offset_x, new_w, factor_x)):
        #print(y, x, value)
        new_arr[y,x] = value
        
print(new_arr)
```

gives

```
[[255   0   0   0 255   0   0   0 255   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0   0   0 255   0   0   0 255   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [255   0   0   0 255   0   0   0 255   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending is simple with slicing:

```
array = np.array([[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]])
factor = 2

extended_array = np.zeros((array.shape[0]*factor, array.shape[1]*factor))
extended_array[::factor,::factor] = array
```